# Why am I getting subscript out of range error on VBA?

Tags: vba

I'm refactoring a code that analyzes 12 tickers and returns the total volume and the return for each ticker. I am getting an out-of-range error for step 3a, and I don't know why. Any ideas why?

```vb
Sub AllStocksAnalysisRefactored()
    'Define startTime and endTime as variables
    Dim startTime As Single
    Dim endTime  As Single

    'Ask the client what year they would like to run with input box.
    yearValue = InputBox("What year would you like to run the analysis on?")

    'Start timer
    startTime = Timer
    
    'Format the output sheet on All Stocks Analysis worksheet
    Worksheets("All Stock Analysis").Activate
    
    Range("A1").Value = "All Stocks (" + yearValue + ")"
    
    'Create a header row on All Stocks Analysis worksheet
    Cells(3, 1).Value = "Ticker"
    Cells(3, 2).Value = "Total Daily Volume"
    Cells(3, 3).Value = "Return"

    'Initialize array of all tickers
    Dim tickers(12) As String
    
    tickers(0) = "AY"
    tickers(1) = "CSIQ"
    tickers(2) = "DQ"
    tickers(3) = "ENPH"
    tickers(4) = "FSLR"
    tickers(5) = "HASI"
    tickers(6) = "JKS"
    tickers(7) = "RUN"
    tickers(8) = "SEDG"
    tickers(9) = "SPWR"
    tickers(10) = "TERP"
    tickers(11) = "VSLR"
    
    'Activate data worksheet
    Worksheets(yearValue).Activate
    
    'Get the number of rows to loop over
    RowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    '1a) Create a ticker Index
    Dim tickerIndex As Single
    tickerIndex = 0

    '1b) Create three output arrays
    Dim tickerVolumes(12) As Long
    
    Dim tickerStartingPrices(12) As Single
   
    Dim tickerEndingPrices(12) As Single
    
    
    ''2a) Create a for loop to initialize the tickerVolumes to zero.
    For i = 0 To 11
    tickerVolumes(i) = 0
    
        
    ''2b) Loop over all the rows in the spreadsheet.
        For j = 2 To RowCount
    
        '3a) Increase volume for current ticker
            **tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) = tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) + Cells(j, 8).Value**
        
        '3b) Check if the current row is the first row with the selected tickerIndex.
        'If  Then
         If Cells(j - 1, 1).Value <> Cells(j, 1) Then
            tickerStartingPrices(tickerIndex) = Cells(j, 6).Value
            
        'End If
        End If
        
        '3c) check if the current row is the last row with the selected ticker
         'If the next row’s ticker doesn’t match, increase the tickerIndex.
        'If  Then
            If Cells(j + 1).Value <> Cells(j, 1) Then
                tickerEndingPrices(tickerIndex) = Cells(j, 6).Value
            

            '3d Increase the tickerIndex.
                tickerIndex = tickerIndex + 1
            
        'End If
        End If
       Next j
    'End For loop
    Next i
    
    '4) Loop through your arrays to output the Ticker, Total Daily Volume, and Return.
    For i = 0 To 11
    
        
        Worksheets("All Stock Analysis").Activate
        tickerIndex = i
        
        Cells(4 + i, 1).Value = tickers(tickerIndex)
        Cells(4 + i, 2).Value = tickerVolumes(tickerIndex)
        Cells(4 + i, 3).Value = tickerEndingPrices(tickerIndex) / tickerStartingPrices(tickerIndex) - 1

    'Format headline with bold and underline
        Worksheets("All Stock Analysis").Activate
        With Range("A3:C3")
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With
        
      'Format number results on All Stock Analysis worksheet
        Range("B4:B15").NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        Range("C4:C15").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        Range("B3:B15").AutoFit
        
     Next i
      'Add green and red background for positive and negative results, respectively. Use a For loop and conditionals.
      'Define variables for first and last row we are adding background color.
        dataRowStart = 4
        dataRowEnd = 15

           'start For loop
                For i = dataRowStart To dataRowEnd
                
        
                'Start conditional
                    If Cells(i, 3) > 0 Then
                        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            
                    Else
                        Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
        
                'End conditional
                    End If
            'End For loop
                Next i
   
  
    'End Timer and print msg on how long it took to run the code.
    endTime = Timer
    MsgBox "This code ran in " & (endTime - startTime) & " seconds for the year " & (yearValue)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `tickerIndex` when the error happens? `0` or `13`? It appears `tickerIndex` is bound to the number of rows / possible iterations of `j`, so if more than 12 rows match the criteria to increment the `tickerIndex`, you're attempting to write beyond the upper bound of the array. If `Option Base 1` is specified at the top of the module, then all implicitly-bound arrays are implicitly 1-based and index `0` is outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Press F9 to place a breakpoint before the loop, then run the macro; when execution stops at the breakpoint, press F8 to run the code line by line, and Ctrl+G to bring up the immediate pane where you can type `?tickerIndex` to get the current value of that variable (or just hover the identifier with the mouse pointer).

Comment: I am getting tickerIndex value 13. Do you know how could I fix this issue?

Comment: The logic for incrementing `tickerIndex` is making assumptions about the shape or size of the data being iterated (is it supposed to be sorted a specific way?). I don't know what your data looks like, but you're in a loop iterating all rows in the sheet and incrementing `tickerIndex` every now and then - but there are only `12` valid indexes, so you can't do that. The algorithm seems wrong, and its intent is hard to infer from its broken implementation. Try describing what the code is supposed to be doing as you read through it, "rubber duck debugging" is a very effective debugging technique!

Answer (score 1):

The outer `i` loop counter appears to be what is intended to be the "current ticker index".

```
For i = 0 To 11
tickerVolumes(i) = 0
```

Consider changing not hard-coding any boundaries and consistently indenting the loop body:

```
For i = LBound(tickerVolumes) To UBound(tickerVolumes)
    tickerVolumes(i) = 0
```

I think you can fix the logic by changing this...

```
Dim tickerIndex As Single
tickerIndex = 0
```

...to this:

```
Dim tickerIndex As Long
```

...and then by deleting the declaration for `i`, and renaming `i` to `tickerIndex`, which changes the outer loop to this:

```
For tickerIndex = LBound(tickerVolumes) To UBound(tickerVolumes)
    tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) = 0
```

Now, there's already a loop taking care of incrementing the `tickerIndex` value, so delete "step 3d", remove any commented-out code and fix the indentation:

```
    For tickerIndex = LBound(tickerVolumes) To UBound(tickerVolumes)
        tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) = 0
    
        
        '2b) Loop over all the rows in the spreadsheet.
        For j = 2 To RowCount
    
            '3a) Increase volume for current ticker
            tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) = tickerVolumes(tickerIndex) + Cells(j, 8).Value
        
            '3b) Check if the current row is the first row with the selected tickerIndex.
            If Cells(j - 1, 1).Value <> Cells(j, 1) Then
                tickerStartingPrices(tickerIndex) = Cells(j, 6).Value            
            End If
        
            '3c) check if the current row is the last row with the selected ticker
            'If the next row’s ticker doesn’t match, increase the tickerIndex.
            If Cells(j + 1).Value <> Cells(j, 1) Then
                tickerEndingPrices(tickerIndex) = Cells(j, 6).Value
            End If
        Next j

    Next tickerIndex
```

It appears the bug stems from using single-letter identifiers and losing their meaning along the way: the role of `i` *was* that of `tickerIndex`; consider renaming `j` to something more meaningful too, like `currentRow`.

Lastly, consider addressing the [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference) to avoid issues when the `ActiveSheet` isn't the sheet your code thinks it is!